# validation message near Textbox not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I am displaying "this field is required" near textbox when there is focus on textbox and when it is empty. I don't want to display that error message when something is already typed in that textbox. I kind of achieved that through this code. The problem here for me though is when textbox is empty and I keep typing backspace key or any other non-character key the "this field is required" span element keep piling up which is not good. how do I solve this?

html

```
<input data-required="true" type="text" name="foo" />
<select data-required="true" >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$("input[data-required='true'],select[data-required='true']").focus(function() {

  $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');

}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next('span').remove();
}).change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put first error message in `if` condition.

```
if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
  $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/hjeo4851/3/)

---

And I changed your code, you would like to use this version:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/hjeo4851/1/)**

Comment: thanks. your first jsfiddle works, but i am trying to display "this field is required" back when you type some characters in textbox and then you empty it.do you know how to do that?

Comment: You mean, want show message also when user is typing? @avi

Comment: yes, when user types some characters in textbox and then he decide to backspace all those character and empty textbox then i should be able to display message back while on focus on textbox.

Comment: No.sorry. i am probably not clear to you. so when i type character "a" in textbox, the message should not be there since it is not empty, and then when i remove charcter "a" from textbox, the message should come back  telling user that this field is required and cannot be empty. @jiff

Comment: Hope this time it be what you want [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/hjeo4851/3/) @avi

Comment: yes, Thank you @jiff . please post this, so i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your chain of event listeners: .focus, .blur, .change,.keyup , change should be all you need, for the select and blur for the text input. Every time focus is removed from the select or input all of these are being triggered, causing multiple spans to be created. when you call $(this).next('span') you are only remove the first span after the element effected.

```
$(function(){
    $("select[data-required='true']").change(function() {

      req( $(this) );

    });
    $("input[data-required='true']").blur(function() {

      req( $(this) );

    });
});
function req( item )
{
    //item = $("input[data-required='true']");
    item.next('span').remove();
    if ($.trim(item.val()).length <= 0) {
        item.after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
    }
}
```